# Using Scrum on a side project

Tags: scrum

I currently use Scrum for the projects i work on day to day. A few of us are now to do a side project to create a new build server for the company. We will  only get a few hours a week on this project so it will take a few months.

Can Scrum work for a project like this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, although you probably won’t need a lot of the ceremony that many people (wrongly) associate with Scrum.

Remember that, at its core, Scrum consists of just this:

- deliver something to production regularly (often every month)
- reflect on what we did and try to improve

You almost certainly don’t need all the roles and artifacts and meetings to get value from Scrum. On the contrary, stripping it down to the basics will likely help you use what little time you have more effectively. In particular, **deliver something to production regularly** should strongly encourage you to focus on a small, valuable, achievable goal. In this particular area, Scrum can really help.

So start with these important questions:

1. Can we get a build server running in production for the company this week? (If you can, then is there anything at all more urgent to do than this?)
2. Assuming that we can’t get a build server running in production this week, what could we get running in production that moves in the direction of having a build server that someone would find valuable?
3. Assuming that we can’t do even that, what could we get running *somewhere* that movies in the direction of having a build server that would explore some risky/unknown/uncertain/difficult aspect of what we’re trying to do?

This will help you decide what to do with your few hours this week. After you’ve done the work, grab some coffee/tea/whatever you like to drink, find a place to sit down, grab something to write with and something to write on. Ask yourselves these three questions:

- What’s left to do to be able to deliver something to production by the end of the month? (In your case, maybe “four-week cycle”.)
- What will we do the same way next week?
- What do we need to do differently next week?

As soon as you identify something that you need to do differently next week, you’ll think of ideas about how to do it. Then you’ll propose to each other, “Let’s do X instead of Y when we get together to work on this next week.” It shouldn’t take long to agree on something.

That’s it. That’s the essence of Scrum. I doubt that you need anything more than that.

Comment: I think you've just described Agile, rather than Scrum specifically. Surely the core of Scrum is, well, a scrum? Of course, there's nothing wrong with your advice!

Comment: First, thank you for your kind words.

More importantly, though, I've described Scrum: deliver every month + inspect and adapt. Everything else is merely a suggestion on how to achieve that from a typical context. Somehow this idea has got lost in the intervening decade.

I suppose you might decide that Daily Scrum is an essential part of Scrum. Although I didn't mention it by name in my answer, assuming they work once per week, they'll need a Weekly Scrum to decide what to do that week.

Comment: Agree--great advice, and a good answer for DasDave.  I'd just say that if you aren't having a sprint planning meeting and daily scrums, you ain't doing Scrum, merely getting inspiration from Scrum, which is defined here: http://www.scrumguides.org/scrum-guide.html